# Grails 3 with Geb fails on "angular-moment"

Tags: grails, gradle, geb, grails-test

I am trying to setup Geb with Grails 3. (I am running it from Intellij)
We are currently implementing an api without any ux. For us it's enough to 
test REST API requests.

I start the tests via `test-app` as I can see in the console log. The tests
break on the error:

> :karmaRun
>
> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
>     Error: Moment cannot be found by angular-moment! Please reference to: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment
>     at grails-app/assets/bower/angular/angular-moment.js:27

I don't even want to have karma running.

**Question**

Either: How can I correct the error above?
Or (preferrably): How to disable/remove any ux test parts like karma from the test run?

Answer (score 1):

you have something else firing off to run the Karma tests. take a look at the stock project here https://github.com/basejump/grails3-geb-example.

try `grails test-app YourFuncTest -integration` to isolate it to just your Geb test?

Comment: Yep, I do. I removed the karma plugins from the `build.gradle`. It helped. I just forgot to update the question.